# Failed to resolve module specifier "axios"

Tags: javascript, axios, type-error

Мне нужна Ваша помощь в поиске ошибки.

Я не понимаю что не так.

```
    import axios from 'axios';
// import process from 'process';

const TOKEN = process.env.TOKEN;
const CHAT_ID = '-*************';
const URL_API = `https://api.telegram.org/bot${TOKEN}/sendMessage`;
const success = document.getElementById('success');

document.getElementById('tg').addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  let message = `<b>Заявка с сайта!</b>\n`;
  message += `<b>Отправитель: </b> ${this.name.value}\n`;
  message += `<b>Телефон: </b> ${this.tel.value}\n`;
  message += `<b>Имя пользователя: </b> ${this.comment.value}`;

  axios
    .post(URL_API, {
      chat_id: CHAT_ID,
      parse_mode: 'html',
      text: message,
    })
    .then(res => {
      this.name.value = '';
      this.tel.value = '';
      this.comment.value = '';
      success.innerHTML = 'Сообщение отправлено!';
      success.style.display = 'block';
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.warn(err);
    })
    .finally(() => {
      console.log('Отправили!');
    });
});
```

Ошибка:
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "axios". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".

Comment: В проекте установлен модуль `axios`?

Comment: @ksa да, через npm i axios

Comment: Где выполняется твой модуль? Непосредственно в браузере? Если так - то тебе поможет прочтение этой статейки https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/failed-to-resolve-module-specifier-javascript#failed-to-resolve-module-specifier-relative-references-must-start-with-either

Comment: Вполне возможно что от тебя требуют `CDN`-подключения, т.е. вот такого использования `import axios from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/axios@1.1.2/dist/axios.min.js'` или другой УРЛ со своего ресурса...

Comment: @ksa так заработало import axios from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/axios@1.1.2/dist/axios.min.js', но теперь показывает Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "process". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".

Comment: Вам нужен какой-то сборщик.

Comment: Значит твои модули запускаются непосредственно в браузере и тебе для всех "внешних" модулей будет требоваться `CDN` подключение.

Comment: Вот статейка про "сборщик" `Webpack` - https://habr.com/ru/articles/514838/

Comment: Или `Parcel` - https://habr.com/ru/companies/ruvds/articles/473764/